# Fragments Incompatible types

Tags: android, java, android-fragment

Здравствуйте!
Есть активити наследующая `ActoinBarActivity`,в ней описывается боковое меню `(NavigationDrawer)`, по нажатию на его элементы открываются фрагменты. В одном из фрагментов есть `listView`, по нажатию на элемент которого, я хочу открывать другой фрагмент (т.е. Сотрудники-список сотрудников - данные сотрудника).
Но у меня выходит ошибка [image]

Comment: `EmployeeDetails` не является фрагментом

Comment: @monomi является. 
        public class EmployeeDetails extends Fragment {

Comment: Может у вас 

    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

а надо 

    import android.app.Fragment;

или наоборот.

Comment: @Garf1eld, да. Вы решите сразу, нужны вам старые версии (и support library вообще) или нет. Если нужны, тогда используйте фрагменты из support library везде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@Yura Ivanov](/users/6117/yura-ivanov)](/users/6117/yura-ivanov) указал мне на верное решение!
сделал импорты `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

вместо

import `android.app.Fragment;`